# Problema cuando importo datos (Field 'id' expected a number but got....) cuando en el dataset aparece el Id

Tags: django, python-import

buenas estoy intentando importar un excel con clave foranea, cuando importa el archivo sale el error cuando en el dataset aparece ese id
Ese metodo esta dentro del `class ProcesionResource(resources.ModelResource)`

admin.py:

class HermanosResource(resources.ModelResource):

```
fields=(
    'apellidos',
    'nombre',
    'direccion',
    )
class Meta:
    model=Personas
```

@admin.register(Personas)
class PersonaAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
list_display=('apellidos','nombre', 'direccion')
resource_class= HermanosResource

class ProcesionResource(resources.ModelResource):

```
class Meta:
    model=Procesion
    fields=('id','hermano','puesto_pedido', 'fecha',)

def __init__(self):
    super(ProcesionResource,self).__init__()
    # Obtenga todos los campos en el modelo Libro en la aplicación de tablas, cambie las tablas de acuerdo con su aplicación
    
    field_list=apps.get_model('cofradia', 'Procesion')._meta.fields
    self.vname_dict={}
    self.fkey=[]
    for i in field_list:
        self.vname_dict[i.name] = i.verbose_name # Obtenga el verbose_name de todos los campos y guárdelos en el diccionario    
        if(isinstance(i, models.ForeignKey)):
            self.fkey.append(i.name)             # Obtenga los nombres de todos los campos ForeignKey almacenados en la lista  

def export(self,queryset=None,*args,**kwargs):
    self.before_export(queryset,*args,**kwargs)

    if queryset is None:
        queryset=self.get_queryset()

    headers=self.get_export_headers()
    data=tablib.Dataset(headers=headers)
                                            # Obtener la posición de todos los nombres de claves externas en los encabezados

    fk_index={}
    for fk in self.fkey:
        fk_index[fk]=headers.index(fk)

    iterable=queryset
    for obj in iterable:
#       # Obtenga los datos de origen para exportar, donde export_resource devuelve una lista para una fácil modificación.
#       # Reemplazado por el valor de la clave externa
        
        res=self.export_resource(obj)

#       #Aquí está la clave, obtenga el objeto correspondiente del valor del propietario al Usuario 
#       #e intercepte el nombre de usuario legible,
```

## #Aquí está get, por lo que el nombre de usuario debe ser único en el modelo de usuario

```
        res[fk_index['hermano']] = Personas.objects.get(id=res[fk_index['hermano']]).apellidos+', '+Personas.objects.get(id=res[fk_index['hermano']]).nombre #aqui es donde cambio el id por esos dos campos
        
        data.append(res)

    self.after_export(queryset,data,*args,**kwargs)
    return data

def before_import(self,dataset,using_transactions,dry_run,**kwargs):

    dict = []

    for row in dataset.dict:
        tmp = collections.OrderedDict()
        hermanos = Personas.objects.all()

        for item in row:
            if item == 'hermano':
                tmp[item]=Personas.objects.get(apellidos=(row[item][0:row[item].find(',')])).id
                print(tmp[item])
            else:
                print(row[item])
                tmp[item]=row[item]

        # for h in hermanos:
        #   if row['hermano'][0:row[item].find(',')]==h.apellidos:
        #       tmp['id']=h.id

    dict.append(tmp)
    dataset = dict
    print(dict)
    return dataset
```

@admin.register(Procesion)
class ProcesionAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):

```
list_display=('hermano','puesto_pedido', 'fecha',)
resource_class= ProcesionResource
```

de `row[item][0:row[item].find(',')])` saco el el apellido de un la columna donde tengo apellidos y nombre concatenados

Imprimo y me sale el valor correcto en el dataset pero no lo coge. Intenta importar sin hacer el cambio.

Comment: Qué suspense!! **Field 'id' expected a number but got...** Qué?! Qué obtuvo?? Este cliffhanger es más duro que los de los vigilantes de la playa.

Comment: El problema viene porque en vez de importar un int, me importa una cadeana.
En vez de exportar la clave foranea como un int, yo lo que hago que me exporte dos campos diferentes (es decir, campo apellidos y nombre). Al importar es cuando da el error a pesar de mandar por el dataset el id